# Proving (a ↔ a) → a in LEAN3

Tags: logic, automated-theorem-proving

I'm trying to proof (a ↔ a) → a in lean, but I can't figure out which lemmas/tactics to use.
Proving a → (a ↔ a) is something I can do.

Can someone guide me with the steps necessary to take to solve the goal?

> example (a : Prop) : (a ↔ a) → a :=
> begin
> intros h,
> end

Comment: This isn't provable - $a \leftrightarrow a$ is a tautology

Comment: Welcome! [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)